# ANDROID - How to send the mail from the webview if not use the <a href tag in html?

Tags: android, webview

Usually I called the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method to call the email client in android, if the webview contains below code

```
 <a href="mailto:test@test.com" style="text-decoration: underline">test@test.com</a>
```

but current webview has written like below code

```
<span class="underline" onclick="openMail('test@test.com')">test@test.com</span>
```

So if I use the below code

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if (url.contains("test@test.com")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "test@test.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
    webview.loadUrl(url);
}
```

JavaScript code like this

```
$(function(){
$(".question").on("click",function(){
    if( $(this).next(".answer").css("display") == "none" ){
        $(this).next(".answer").show();
        $(this).addClass("unfold");
    } else {
        $(this).next(".answer").hide();
        $(this).next(".answer").find(".answerinner").hide();
        $(this).removeClass("unfold");
    }
});
$(".title_h5").on("click",function(){
    if( $(this).next(".answerinner").css("display") == "none" ){
        $(this).next(".answerinner").show();    
    } else {
        $(this).next(".answerinner").hide();
    }
});
});
var browser = {
    versions: function () {
        var u = navigator.userAgent, app = navigator.appVersion;
        return { 
            ios: !!u.match(/\(i[^;]+;( U;)? CPU.+Mac OS X/),
            android: u.indexOf('Android') > -1 || u.indexOf('Linux') > -1, 
            iPhone: u.indexOf('iPhone') > -1,
            iPad: u.indexOf('iPad') > -1,
        };
    }(),
}
function connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(callback) {
    if (window.WebViewJavascriptBridge) {
        callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('WebViewJavascriptBridgeReady', function() {
            callback(WebViewJavascriptBridge)
        }, false)
    }
}
function openMail(mailAddress) {
    if (browser.versions.iPhone || browser.versions.iPad || browser.versions.ios) {
        connectWebViewJavascriptBridge(function(bridge) {
            var uniqueId = 1
            bridge.init(function(message, responseCallback) {
                var data = { 'Javascript Responds':'Wee!' }
                responseCallback(data)
            })
            bridge.registerHandler('testJavascriptHandler', function(data, responseCallback) {
                var responseData = { 'Javascript Says':'Right back atcha!' }
                responseCallback(responseData)
            })

            var data = mailAddress;
            bridge.send(data, function(responseData) {
            })
        });
    }
    if (browser.versions.android) {
        window.email.open(mailAddress);
    }
}
```

then it's not open the email client when I click the email in the webview.
Even it's not hit the click even.

I checked the startsWith also

Any Advise ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `openMail('test@test.com')` seems the javascript method.. so you need to check the code of `openMail('test@test.com')` I think that method will contain this  code `window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message";` or something like this.. put that code here

Comment: This is the code they used 
<p class="answer" style="display: block;">
    test 
    <span class="underline" onclick="openMail('test@test.com')">test@test.com</span>
   </p>

this underline class is CSS
and whatever if I click then it's not hit into the shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please check the updated code with javascript.

Comment: I think you should not override for this case because `window.email.open(mailAddress);` it will open mail app.

Comment: or what if this condition `browser.versions.android`  fails on android webview?? may be it is only for android webkit browser. In that case no any contidion will run?

Comment: Thanks. If I call the mailAddress then it's working...

public class JsInteration {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void open(String mailAddress) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + "test@test.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInteration(), "email");